# input 0 is not defined stack:reference error

Tags: javascript, undefined, referenceerror

I am using scw date picker library. Javascript code that I used for a long time doesn't work now. `onclick` function of input works on the first row but doesn't work on second and other rows.

I created the inputs dynamically with javascript codes.

**JavaScript Codes**

```
function AddRow(tbody_id, satir_id)
{
  var tbody = document.getElementById(tbody_id);
  var row = document.createElement("tr");

  row.id = "s" + satir_id;

  var input0 = document.createElement("input");

  input0.id = row.id + "_i0";
  input0.name = "satir[" + satir_id+ "][0]";
  input0.className = "text";
  input0.size = "11";
  input0.onclick = function onclick()
  {
     scwNextAction = tmp.runAfterSCW(this);
     scwShow(this, event);
  }
}
```

At this `input0.onclick` method work on first row. But it doesn't work on second and another rows.

Error is like below:

input0 is not defined 
stack:"ReferenceError: input0 is not defined↵    at eval (eval at positiontip (http://portaltest.gural.tr/phpgroupware/kys/siparis/ortak/kutuphane/form.js?v2.0.1035:1:1), :1:1)↵    at HTMLDocument.positiontip (http://portaltest.gural.tr/phpgroupware/kys/siparis/ortak/kutuphane/form.js?v2.0.1035:334:21)"

The same code works at internet explorer but doesn't work at google crome. There is reference error at both of them(internet explorer,google chrome).

Do you think how can I fix this situation?

Answer (score 0):

Can you try to addEventListener instead of using onclick property

```
function AddRow(tbody_id, satir_id)
{
  var tbody = document.getElementById(tbody_id);
  var row = document.createElement("tr");

  row.id = "s" + satir_id;

  var input0 = document.createElement("input");

  input0.id = row.id + "_i0";
  input0.name = "satir[" + satir_id+ "][0]";
  input0.className = "text";
  input0.size = "11";
  input0.addEventlistener("click", function(evt) {
      scwNextAction = tmp.runAfterSCW(this);
      scwShow(this, evt);
  })
}
```

Else, do you have reference to `input0` in `tmp.runAfterSCW()` or `scwShow()` ?

Answer (score 0):

I have scw.js for scw date picker library.
        for runsAfterSCW function:
    Function.prototype.runsAfterSCW =
        function()  {var func = this,
                         args = new Array(arguments.length);

```
                 for (var i=0;i<args.length;++i) {args[i] = arguments[i];}

                 return function()
                    {// concat/join the two argument arrays
                     for (var i=0;i<arguments.length;++i) {args[args.length] = arguments[i];}
                     return (args.shift()==scwTriggerEle)?func.apply(this, args):null;
                    };
    };


  For scwShow function:
  function scwShow(scwEle,scwSource)
    {if (!scwSource) {scwSource = window.event;}

     if (scwSource.tagName) // Second parameter isn't an event it's an element
        {var scwSourceEle = scwSource;

         if (scwID('scwIE'))  {window.event.cancelBubble = true;}
         else {scwSourceEle.parentNode.addEventListener('click',scwStopPropagation,false);}
        }
     else   // Second parameter is an event
        {var scwSourceEle = (scwSource.target)
                                ?scwSource.target
                                :scwSource.srcElement;

         // Stop the click event that opens the calendar from bubbling up to
         // the document-level event handler that hides it!
         if (scwSource.stopPropagation) {scwSource.stopPropagation();}
         else                           {scwSource.cancelBubble = true;}
        }

     scwTriggerEle = scwSourceEle;

     // Take any parameters that there might be from the third onwards as
     // day numbers to be disabled 0 = Sunday through to 6 = Saturday.

     scwParmActiveToday = true;

     for (var i=0;i<7;i++)
        {scwPassEnabledDay[(i+7-scwWeekStart)%7] = true;
         for (var j=2;j<arguments.length;j++)
            {if (arguments[j]==i)
                {scwPassEnabledDay[(i+7-scwWeekStart)%7] = false;
                 if (scwDateNow.getDay()==i) {scwParmActiveToday = false;}
                }
            }
        }

     //   If no value is preset then the seed date is
     //      Today (when today is in range) OR
     //      The middle of the date range.

     scwSeedDate = scwDateNow;

     // Find the date and Strip space characters from start and
     // end of date input.

     var scwDateValue = '';

     if (scwEle.value) {scwDateValue = scwEle.value.replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,'');}
     else   {if (typeof scwEle.value == 'undefined')
                {var scwChildNodes = scwEle.childNodes;
                 for (var i=0;i<scwChildNodes.length;i++)
                    {if (scwChildNodes[i].nodeType == 3)
                        {scwDateValue = scwChildNodes[i].nodeValue.replace(/^\s+/,'').replace(/\s+$/,'');
                         if (scwDateValue.length > 0)
                            {scwTriggerEle.scwTextNode = scwChildNodes[i];
                             scwTriggerEle.scwLength   = scwChildNodes[i].nodeValue.length;
                             break;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

     // Set the language-dependent elements

     scwSetDefaultLanguage();

     scwID('scwDragText').innerHTML = scwDrag;

     scwID('scwMonths').options.length = 0;
     for (var i=0;i<scwArrMonthNames.length;i++)
        {scwID('scwMonths').options[i] = new Option(scwArrMonthNames[i],scwArrMonthNames[i]);}

     scwID('scwYears').options.length = 0;
     for (var i=0;i<scwDropDownYears;i++)
        {scwID('scwYears').options[i] =  new Option((scwBaseYear+i),(scwBaseYear+i));}

     for (var i=0;i<scwArrWeekInits.length;i++)
        {scwID('scwWeekInit' + i).innerHTML = scwArrWeekInits[(i+scwWeekStart)%scwArrWeekInits.length];}

     if (((new Date(scwBaseYear + scwDropDownYears, 0, 0)) > scwDateNow &&
          (new Date(scwBaseYear, 0, 0))                    < scwDateNow) ||
         (scwClearButton && (scwEle.readOnly || scwEle.disabled))
        )   {scwID('scwFoot').style.display = '';
             scwID('scwNow').innerHTML = scwToday + ' ' + scwDateNow.scwFormat(scwDateDisplayFormat);
             scwID('scwClearButton').value = scwClear;
             if ((new Date(scwBaseYear + scwDropDownYears, 0, 0)) > scwDateNow &&
                 (new Date(scwBaseYear, 0, 0))                    < scwDateNow
                )   {scwID('scwNow').style.display = '';
                     if (scwClearButton && (scwEle.readOnly || scwEle.disabled))
                            {scwID('scwClear').style.display   = '';
                             scwID('scwClear').style.textAlign = 'left';
                             scwID('scwNow').style.textAlign   = 'right';
                            }
                     else   {scwID('scwClear').style.display = 'none';
                             scwID('scwNow').style.textAlign = 'center';
                            }
                    }
             else   {scwID('scwClear').style.textAlign = 'center';
                     scwID('scwClear').style.display = '';
                     scwID('scwNow').style.display = 'none';
                    }
            }
     else   {scwID('scwFoot').style.display = 'none';}

     if (scwDateValue.length==0)
        {// If no value is entered and today is within the range,
         // use today's date, otherwise use the middle of the valid range.

         scwBlnFullInputDate=false;

         if ((new Date(scwBaseYear+scwDropDownYears,0,0))<scwSeedDate ||
             (new Date(scwBaseYear,0,1))                 >scwSeedDate
            )
            {scwSeedDate = new Date(scwBaseYear + Math.floor(scwDropDownYears / 2), 5, 1);}
        }
     else
        {function scwInputFormat()
            {var scwArrSeed = new Array(),
                 scwArrInput = scwDateValue.split(new RegExp('[\\'+scwArrDelimiters.join('\\')+']+','g'));

             // "Escape" all the user defined date delimiters above -
             // several delimiters will need it and it does no harm for
             // the others.

             // Strip any empty array elements (caused by delimiters)
             // from the beginning or end of the array. They will
             // still appear in the output string if in the output
             // format.

             if (scwArrInput[0]!=null)
                {if (scwArrInput[0].length==0)                      {scwArrInput.splice(0,1);}
                 if (scwArrInput[scwArrInput.length-1].length==0)   {scwArrInput.splice(scwArrInput.length-1,1);}
                }

             scwBlnFullInputDate = false;

             scwDateOutputFormat = scwDateOutputFormat.toUpperCase();

             // List all the allowed letters in the date format
             var template = ['D','M','Y']; 

             // Prepare the sequence of date input elements
             var result = new Array();

             for (var i=0;i<template.length;i++)
                {if (scwDateOutputFormat.search(template[i])>-1)
                    {result[scwDateOutputFormat.search(template[i])] = template[i];}
                }

             var scwDateSequence = result.join('');

             // Separate the elements of the date input
             switch (scwArrInput.length)
                {case 1:
                    {if (scwDateOutputFormat.indexOf('Y')>-1 &&
                         scwArrInput[0].length>scwDateOutputFormat.lastIndexOf('Y'))
                        {scwArrSeed[0] = parseInt(scwArrInput[0].substring(scwDateOutputFormat.indexOf('Y'),
                                                                           scwDateOutputFormat.lastIndexOf('Y')+1),10);
                        }
                     else   {scwArrSeed[0] = 0;}

                     if (scwDateOutputFormat.indexOf('M')>-1 &&
                         scwArrInput[0].length>scwDateOutputFormat.lastIndexOf('M'))
                        {scwArrSeed[1] = scwArrInput[0].substring(scwDateOutputFormat.indexOf('M'),
                                                                  scwDateOutputFormat.lastIndexOf('M')+1);
                        }
                     else   {scwArrSeed[1] = '6';}

                     if (scwDateOutputFormat.indexOf('D')>-1 &&
                         scwArrInput[0].length>scwDateOutputFormat.lastIndexOf('D'))
                        {scwArrSeed[2] = parseInt(scwArrInput[0].substring(scwDateOutputFormat.indexOf('D'),
                                                                           scwDateOutputFormat.lastIndexOf('D')+1),10);
                        }
                     else   {scwArrSeed[2] = 1;}

                     if (scwArrInput[0].length==scwDateOutputFormat.length) {scwBlnFullInputDate = true;}
                     break;
                    }
                 case 2:
                    {// Year and Month entry
                     scwArrSeed[0] =
                         parseInt(scwArrInput[scwDateSequence.
                                                replace(/D/i,'').
                                                search(/Y/i)],10);  // Year
                     scwArrSeed[1] = scwArrInput[scwDateSequence.
                                                replace(/D/i,'').
                                                search(/M/i)];      // Month
                     scwArrSeed[2] = 1;                             // Day
                     break;
                    }
                 case 3:
                    {// Day Month and Year entry

                     scwArrSeed[0] =
                         parseInt(scwArrInput[scwDateSequence.
                                                search(/Y/i)],10);  // Year
                     scwArrSeed[1] = scwArrInput[scwDateSequence.
                                                search(/M/i)];      // Month
                     scwArrSeed[2] =
                         parseInt(scwArrInput[scwDateSequence.
                                                search(/D/i)],10);  // Day

                     scwBlnFullInputDate = true;
                     break;
                    }
                 default:
                    {// A stuff-up has led to more than three elements in
                     // the date.
                     scwArrSeed[0] = 0;     // Year
                     scwArrSeed[1] = 0;     // Month
                     scwArrSeed[2] = 0;     // Day
                    }
                }

             // These regular expressions validate the input date format
             // to the following rules;
             //         Day   1-31 (optional zero on single digits)
             //         Month 1-12 (optional zero on single digits)
             //                     or case insensitive name
             //         Year  One, Two or four digits

             // Months names are as set in the language-dependent
             // definitions and delimiters are set just below there

             var scwExpValDay    = new RegExp('^(0?[1-9]|[1-2][0-9]|3[0-1])$'),
                 scwExpValMonth  = new RegExp('^(0?[1-9]|1[0-2]|'        +
                                              scwArrMonthNames.join('|') +
                                              ')$','i'),
                 scwExpValYear   = new RegExp('^([0-9]{1,2}|[0-9]{4})$');

             // Apply validation and report failures

             if (scwExpValYear.exec(scwArrSeed[0])  == null ||
                 scwExpValMonth.exec(scwArrSeed[1]) == null ||
                 scwExpValDay.exec(scwArrSeed[2])   == null
                )
                {if (scwShowInvalidDateMsg)
                    {alert(scwInvalidDateMsg  +
                           scwInvalidAlert[0] + scwDateValue +
                           scwInvalidAlert[1]);}
                 scwBlnFullInputDate = false;
                 scwArrSeed[0] = scwBaseYear +
                                 Math.floor(scwDropDownYears/2); // Year
                 scwArrSeed[1] = '6';                            // Month
                 scwArrSeed[2] = 1;                              // Day
                }

             // Return the  Year    in scwArrSeed[0]
             //             Month   in scwArrSeed[1]
             //             Day     in scwArrSeed[2]

             return scwArrSeed;
            };

         // Parse the string into an array using the allowed delimiters

         scwArrSeedDate = scwInputFormat();

         // So now we have the Year, Month and Day in an array.

         //   If the year is one or two digits then the routine assumes a
         //   year belongs in the 21st Century unless it is less than 50
         //   in which case it assumes the 20th Century is intended.

         if (scwArrSeedDate[0]<100) {scwArrSeedDate[0] += (scwArrSeedDate[0]>50)?1900:2000;}

         // Check whether the month is in digits or an abbreviation

         if (scwArrSeedDate[1].search(/\d+/)<0)
            {for (i=0;i<scwArrMonthNames.length;i++)
                {if (scwArrSeedDate[1].toUpperCase()==scwArrMonthNames[i].toUpperCase())
                    {scwArrSeedDate[1]=i+1;
                     break;
                    }
                }
            }

         scwSeedDate = new Date(scwArrSeedDate[0],scwArrSeedDate[1]-1,scwArrSeedDate[2]);
        }

     // Test that we have arrived at a valid date

     if (isNaN(scwSeedDate))
        {if (scwShowInvalidDateMsg) {alert(scwInvalidDateMsg + scwInvalidAlert[0] + scwDateValue + scwInvalidAlert[1]);}
         scwSeedDate = new Date(scwBaseYear + Math.floor(scwDropDownYears/2),5,1);
         scwBlnFullInputDate=false;
        }
     else
        {// Test that the date is within range,
         // if not then set date to a sensible date in range.

         if ((new Date(scwBaseYear,0,1)) > scwSeedDate)
            {if (scwBlnStrict && scwShowOutOfRangeMsg) {alert(scwOutOfRangeMsg);}
             scwSeedDate = new Date(scwBaseYear,0,1);
             scwBlnFullInputDate=false;
            }
         else
            {if ((new Date(scwBaseYear+scwDropDownYears,0,0))<scwSeedDate)
                {if (scwBlnStrict && scwShowOutOfRangeMsg) {alert(scwOutOfRangeMsg);}
                 scwSeedDate = new Date(scwBaseYear + Math.floor(scwDropDownYears)-1,11,1);
                 scwBlnFullInputDate=false;
                }
             else
                {if (scwBlnStrict && scwBlnFullInputDate &&
                      (scwSeedDate.getDate()      != scwArrSeedDate[2] ||
                       (scwSeedDate.getMonth()+1) != scwArrSeedDate[1] ||
                       scwSeedDate.getFullYear()  != scwArrSeedDate[0]
                      )
                    )
                    {if (scwShowDoesNotExistMsg) alert(scwDoesNotExistMsg);
                     scwSeedDate = new Date(scwSeedDate.getFullYear(),scwSeedDate.getMonth()-1,1);
                     scwBlnFullInputDate=false;
                    }
                }
            }
        }

     // Test the disabled dates for validity
     // Give error message if not valid.

     for (var i=0;i<scwDisabledDates.length;i++)
        {if (!((typeof scwDisabledDates[i] == 'object') && (scwDisabledDates[i].constructor == Date)))
            {if ((typeof scwDisabledDates[i] == 'object') && (scwDisabledDates[i].constructor == Array))
                {var scwPass = true;

                 if (scwDisabledDates[i].length !=2)
                    {if (scwShowRangeDisablingError)
                        {alert(scwRangeDisablingError[0] + scwDisabledDates[i] + scwRangeDisablingError[1]);}
                     scwPass = false;
                    }
                 else
                    {for (var j=0;j<scwDisabledDates[i].length;j++)
                        {if (!((typeof scwDisabledDates[i][j] == 'object') && (scwDisabledDates[i][j].constructor == Date)))
                            {if (scwShowRangeDisablingError)
                                {alert(  scwDateDisablingError[0] + scwDisabledDates[i][j] + scwDateDisablingError[1]);}
                             scwPass = false;
                            }
                        }
                    }

                 if (scwPass && (scwDisabledDates[i][0] > scwDisabledDates[i][1])) {scwDisabledDates[i].reverse();}
                }
             else
                {if (scwShowRangeDisablingError) {alert(scwDateDisablingError[0] + scwDisabledDates[i] + scwDateDisablingError[1]);}}
            }
        }

     // Calculate the number of months that the entered (or
     // defaulted) month is after the start of the allowed
     // date range.

     scwMonthSum =  12*(scwSeedDate.getFullYear()-scwBaseYear)+scwSeedDate.getMonth();

     scwID('scwYears' ).options.selectedIndex = Math.floor(scwMonthSum/12);
     scwID('scwMonths').options.selectedIndex = (scwMonthSum%12);

     // Check whether or not dragging is allowed and display drag handle if necessary

     scwID('scwDrag').style.display=(scwAllowDrag)?'':'none';

     // Display the month

     scwShowMonth(0);

     // Position the calendar box

     // The object sniffing for Opera allows for the fact that Opera
     // is the only major browser that correctly reports the position
     // of an element in a scrollable DIV.  This is because IE and
     // Firefox omit the DIV from the offsetParent tree.

     scwTargetEle=scwEle;

     var offsetTop =parseInt(scwEle.offsetTop ,10) + parseInt(scwEle.offsetHeight,10),
         offsetLeft=parseInt(scwEle.offsetLeft,10);

     if (!window.opera)
         {while (scwEle.tagName!='BODY' && scwEle.tagName!='HTML')
             {offsetTop -=parseInt(scwEle.scrollTop, 10);
              offsetLeft-=parseInt(scwEle.scrollLeft,10);
              scwEle=scwEle.parentNode;
             }
          scwEle=scwTargetEle;
         }

     do {scwEle=scwEle.offsetParent;
         offsetTop +=parseInt(scwEle.offsetTop, 10);
         offsetLeft+=parseInt(scwEle.offsetLeft,10);
        }
     while (scwEle.tagName!='BODY' && scwEle.tagName!='HTML');

     if (scwAutoPosition)
         {var scwWidth      = parseInt(scwID('scw').offsetWidth, 10),
              scwHeight     = parseInt(scwID('scw').offsetHeight,10),
              scwWindowLeft =
                 (document.body && document.body.scrollLeft)
                      ?document.body.scrollLeft                  //DOM compliant
                      :(document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollLeft)
                          ?document.documentElement.scrollLeft   //IE6+ standards compliant
                          :0,                                    //Failed
              scwWindowWidth =
                  (typeof(innerWidth) == 'number')
                      ?innerWidth                                //DOM compliant
                      :(document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientWidth)
                          ?document.documentElement.clientWidth  //IE6+ standards compliant
                          :(document.body && document.body.clientWidth)
                              ?document.body.clientWidth         //IE non-compliant
                              :0,                                //Failed
              scwWindowTop =
                  (document.body && document.body.scrollTop)
                      ?document.body.scrollTop                   //DOM compliant
                      :(document.documentElement && document.documentElement.scrollTop)
                          ?document.documentElement.scrollTop    //IE6+ standards compliant
                          :0,                                    //Failed
              scwWindowHeight =
                  (typeof(innerHeight) == 'number')
                      ?innerHeight                               //DOM compliant
                      :(document.documentElement && document.documentElement.clientHeight)
                          ?document.documentElement.clientHeight //IE6+ standards compliant
                          :(document.body && document.body.clientHeight)
                              ?document.body.clientHeight        //IE non-compliant
                              :0;                                //Failed

          offsetLeft -= (offsetLeft - scwWidth + parseInt(scwTargetEle.offsetWidth,10) >= scwWindowLeft &&
                         offsetLeft + scwWidth > scwWindowLeft + scwWindowWidth
                        )?(scwWidth - parseInt(scwTargetEle.offsetWidth,10)):0;

          offsetTop -= (offsetTop - scwHeight - parseInt(scwTargetEle.offsetHeight,10) >= scwWindowTop &&
                        offsetTop + scwHeight > scwWindowTop + scwWindowHeight
                       )?(scwHeight + parseInt(scwTargetEle.offsetHeight,10)):0;
         }

     scwID('scw').style.top         = offsetTop+'px';
     scwID('scw').style.left        = offsetLeft+'px';
     scwID('scwIframe').style.top   = offsetTop+'px';
     scwID('scwIframe').style.left  = offsetLeft+'px';

     scwID('scwIframe').style.width =(scwID('scw').offsetWidth-(scwID('scwIE')?2:4))+'px';
     scwID('scwIframe').style.height=(scwID('scw').offsetHeight-(scwID('scwIE')?2:4))+'px';
     scwID('scwIframe').style.visibility='inherit';

     // Show it on the page
     scwID('scw').style.visibility='inherit';
    };
```

Comment: You should not put this as an answer... You could try to create a jsfiddle that reproduce the problem instead